# PHP to Javascript, array to array, object to object

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, object

I have a list of image paths in my PHP script that I would like to pass to javascript whitout rendering them in the HTML page. I mean, I don't want people go fishing for the path's when do do a > view HTML source.

```
<?php
    $images_str = "some/dir/001.jpg|*|some/dir/002.jpg|*|some/dir/003.jpg";
    $images_arr = array('some/dir/001.jpg', 'some/dir/002.jpg', 'some/dir/003.jpg');
?>
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var dynamicID = 1;

        /* String */
        _images_str = "<?= $images_str ?>";
        _images_str_arr = _images_str.split("|*|");

        // alert(_images_str_arr[dynamicID]); // OK but renders the image paths in javascript

        /* Array */
        var _images_arr = new Array();
        _images_arr = "<?= $images_arr ?>";

        // alert("<?= $images_arr ?>"); // "Array"
        // alert(_images_arr); // "Array"

        // alert(_images_arr[1]); // "r" from "Array"
        // alert("<?= $images_arr[1] ?>"); // "some/dir/002.jpg" works! but how to use dynamicID??

        // alert("<?= count($images_arr) ?>"); // works as well

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want people go fishing for the
>   path's when do do a > view HTML source

What are you going to do with those image paths in your javascript? If the final goal is to use them as the source of an `img` tag then you could do absolutely nothing to hide them as tools such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will show directly all the HTTP requests that the browser performs, so it's not even necessary to look at the source of the HTML page to obtain the image paths.

If you intend to do something else with these paths (??) you could use a public/private key encryption algorithm. For example you generate a pair of private/public keys in javascript and you use ajax to send the public key to your server script. The script uses this public key to encrypt the image paths and returns them as JSON array to the client script which uses it's private key to decrypt them.

---

UPDATE:

Here's one example of sending the list of paths through AJAX:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $images_arr = array('some/dir/001.jpg', 'some/dir/002.jpg', 'some/dir/003.jpg');
    echo json_encode($images_arr);
?>
```

and you obtain them in javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('/script.php', function(data) {
        for (var x = 0; x < length; x += 1) {
            var imageUrl = data[x];
            // do something with this image url
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I use these paths in a jQuery photo application
I just don't want the average Joe to look in my source and see the .jpg paths in Javascript and than think: "hey, there they are"

Comment: In this case obtain them from the server through an AJAX request.

Comment: AJAX, ok can you just give me some keywords to start looking into this Darin? I am using jQuery btw.

Comment: Please see my update. You could also google http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=php+ajax+jquery+json&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

Comment: @vava, the average `Joe` is not supposed to have FireBug installed :-)

Comment: @Darin, average Joe do not know how to get HTML and find src elements of img tags either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to tell you but you have no choice. If you want JavaScript to use your array, you have to pass it out to client and that means power user will be able to see it. There is no way around.

You can encode it but it won't hold against JavaScript debugger.

If it is visible to JavaScript code, it is visible to user, period.

Comment: I am not interested in power users, just the average who looks at the source and see a .jpg extension

Comment: @FFish, average guy will right-click on image and "copy link location". It won't save you either.

Comment: I disabled right click on the image with jQuery:
    $("#myImage").bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
     return false;
    });

Comment: You just going to annoy whole lot of users and achieve nothing, I tell ya.